# Match Characters after last dot in string

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I have a `string` and I want to get the words after the *last dot* `.` in the string.

Example:

```
string input = "XimEngine.DynamicGui.PickKind.DropDown";
```

Result:

```
DropDown
```

Comment: `string result = input.SubString(input.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a RegEx answer, but you could do:

```
var result = input.Split('.').Last();
```

Answer (score 7):

There's no need in `Regex`, let's find out the last `.` and get `Substring`:

```
 string result = input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

If `input` doesn't have `.` the entire `input` will be returned.

**Edit:** Same code rewritten with a help of *range*:

```
string result = input[(input.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)..];
```

Finally, if you insist on *regular expression*, you can put it as

```
string result = Regex.Match(input, "[^.]*$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Value;
```

We match zero or more symbols which are not dot `.` starting from the *end* of the string (from the right).

Comment: This is written with thinking about performance. It will work faster than input.Split('.').Last();

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Regex you can tell the parser to work from the end of the string/buffer by specifying the option `RightToLeft`.

By using that we can just specify a forward pattern to find a period (`\.`) and then capture (using `( )`) our text we are interested into group 1 (`(\w+)`).

```
var str = "XimEngine.DynamicGui.PickKind.DropDown";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(str, 
                              @"\.(\w+)", 
                              RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[1].Value);
```

Outputs to console:

```
DropDown
```

By working from the other end of the string means we don't have to deal with anything at the beginning of the string to where we need to extract text.